# How to replace an unicode quotation marks with an ascii in ruby 1.8?

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode, ruby-1.8.7

How to find and replace [unicode quotation marks](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html) in ruby 1.8.7? For example, from:

```
“Good morning.”
```

to:

```
'Good morning.'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do normal search and replace, e.g:

```
>> '“Good morning.”'.gsub(%r/“|”/, "'")
=> "'Good morning.'"
```

Comment: `%r[“|”]` would be better written as `%r[“”]` because including '|' in the character class makes it eligible for replacing too: `'“|”'.gsub(/[“|”]/, "'") # => 
"'''"`

Comment: @theTinMan but `'“|”'.gsub(%r[“|”], "'") =>  "'|'"`  with ruby 1.8.7, but tbh you are right and i am unsure why ruby behaves differently with `%r` and `/`

Comment: `%r[“|”]` in Ruby is equivalent to Perl's `qr[“|”]`, or (in either language) `/“|”/`.  The `%r` prefix, like Perl's `qr`, allows you to choose different regex delimiters--for example, you could have written `%r!“|”!` or `%r{“|”}`.  Usually you use this feature to *prevent* confusion, but in this case it seems to be having the opposite effect. ;)